# Case insensitive flag INSIDE an extended regexp

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I need to perform case-insensitive match with the [grepdiff](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grepdiff) tool. Unlike grep it doesn't have an argument for that, but it has `--extended-regexp`. Is it possible?

I tried perl-like, but it doesn't work

```
$ echo SOME | egrep '(?i)some'
$ echo SOME | grepdiff --extended-regexp '(?i)some'
grepdiff: repetition-operator operand invalid
```

Comment: don't know about `grepdiff`... if it is small enough word, try `[sS][oO][mM][eE]`?

Answer (score 3):

You need to tell the `grep` family to use Perl-like REs.

```
echo SOME | grep -P '(?i)some'
SOME
```

Unfortunately this flag is not available in `grepdiff` and, as far as I can see, neither is `-i` (case insensitive match).

Here is a small script, which I've called `pgrepdiff`, which will allow you to use a PCRE to match your `diff` output. It does not accept any of the flags that `grepdiff` allows. It reads from named files or *stdin* if none is provided. Omitting the RE turns it into an expensive `cat` operator:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Usage:  pgrepdiff  <re>  [<files...>]
#
# https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/424566/100397
#
tmpd=$(mktemp --tmpdir --directory 'pgd.XXXXXXXXXX')

re="$1"
shift

# Split the file into its context diff parts
cat "$@" | csplit - -f "$tmpd/xx." -k -n4 -s -z '/^@@/' '{*}'

# Save the header preamble for a match
mv -f "$tmpd/xx.0000" "$tmpd/head"
head=

# Iterate across all the diff segments
shopt -s nullglob
for xx in "$tmpd"/xx.????
do
    if grep -q -P "$re" "$xx"
    then
        [[ -z $head ]] && cat "$tmpd/head" && head=yes
        cat "$xx"
    fi
done

# Tidy up
rm -rf "$tmpd"

# Return 0 (success) iff we matched something
[[ -n $head ]]
```